# Umbraco 7 Multinode Treepicker xpath query root node parent of parent

Tags: xpath, umbraco, content-type, umbraco7, treenode

I have Multinode Treepicker in Umbraco 7.4.1.
I'm trying to find out how to set the picker to start from the parent of the parent of my current node.
I'm also need the option to set the picker to start from the siblings of the parent of my current node.

[image]

I tried to use:

```
$parent/$parent
```

or

```
$parent/parent
```

or

```
../
```

no success...

Thanks in advance for all helpers!

Comment: Try `$parent/..` or `../..`.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! the first option works perfect !!! (the second not work..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hr_117 found the answer !

```
$parent/..
```

thank's

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `xpath` filters like `ancestor-or-self`, etc and use filters like `[self::type]` to find what you want.

So if you want to find an ancestor which is a homepage you can write:

```
$current/ancestor-or-self::*[self::homepage]
```